# How to check $addToSet return true or false in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to check a field (`pv_time`) in document if data is not duplicate then insert data in `pv_time` and other fields also.In others fields duplication is allowed. Using `$addToSet` I'm trying to do this.

Here is my python code:

```
 for row in results.get('rows'):
    path = row[0]
    feedbackId = row[1]
    pvDate = row[2]+' '+row[3]+':'+row[4]
    city = row[5]
    country = row[6]
    pageviews = int(row[7])
    db.customer_feedback_requests_archive.update({'feedback_request_id':ObjectId(feedbackId)},{'$addToSet':{'pv_time.'+path:pvDate},'$push':{'pv_city.'+path:city,'pv_country.'+path:country},'$inc':{'pv_count.'+path:pageviews}})
```

If i run this first time it's gives

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d3900996f95a24aa69ef3"),
        "feedback_request_id" : ObjectId("5665015a882a5174379d4dbd"),
        "pv_count" : {
                "main-rating" : 2
        },
        "pv_city" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "Bengaluru",
                        "Bengaluru"
                ]
        },
        "pv_country" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "India",
                        "India"
                ]
        },
        "pv_time" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "20151208 10:00",
                        "20151208 10:01"
                ]
        }
}
```

But if i run this job two times then it gives:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("558d3900996f95a24aa69ef3"),
        "feedback_request_id" : ObjectId("5665015a882a5174379d4dbd"),
        "pv_count" : {
                "main-rating" : 4
        },
        "pv_city" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "Bengaluru",
                        "Bengaluru",
                        "Bengaluru",
                        "Bengaluru"
                ]
        },
        "pv_country" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "India",
                        "India",
                        "India",
                        "India"
                ]
        },
        "pv_time" : {
                "main-rating" : [
                        "20151208 10:00",
                        "20151208 10:01"
                ]
        }
}
```

I want duplicate values in `pv_city` and `pv_country` only if `pv_time` is different and in second time I'm expecting if `pv_time` is not updated then it should not update `pv_city` and `pv_country`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're structuring your documents this way?

Comment: So you want to add values to pv_city and pv_country only if the current pv_time is different from all the values inside the collection?

Comment: @tonyl7126 yes there is some reason

Comment: is this loop the only place you're doing the update?

Comment: also it might help to know the reason for doing it this way

Comment: @tonyl7126 there is nothing to do with reason. My question is simple...i want to check duplication in one field if not duplicate then insert data in checked field as well as in others fields also that accept duplicate data.

Comment: will this work for you ? db.customer_feedback_requests_archive.update({'feedback_request_id':ObjectId(feedbackId),'pv_time.'+path:{'$ne':pvDate}},{'$addToSet':{'pv_time.'+path:pvDate},'$push':{'pv_city.'+path:city,'pv_country.'+path:country},'$inc':{'pv_count.'+path:pageviews}})

Comment: @SarathNair Yeah! this is working...please put ur comment into the answer.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly simple, you just need to expand your query a little bit.

```
db.customer_feedback_requests_archive.update(
  {'feedback_request_id':ObjectId(fee‌​dbackId),'pv_time.'+path:{'$ne':pvDate}},
  {'$addToSet':{'pv_time.'+path:pvDate},'$‌​push':{'pv_city.'+path:city,'pv_country.'+path:country},'$inc':{'pv_count.'+path:‌​pageviews}}
)
```

What the extra query parameter does is that, it will search if the array already has the date. If its not present, the update is going to fire which will solve your issue.